# How to add two random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given that $$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{X} & -1 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{p} & 0.2 & ? & 0.3 \\
\end{array}$$
and 
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{Y} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \text{p} & ? & 0.4 & 0.3 \\
\end{array}$$

how can I write $X+Y$?

EDIT:
Question marks are supposed to be unknown values of corresponding probabilities. E.g. probability of X being 1 is unknown. And yes, they are independent.

By calculating the values at question marks, I get:

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{X} & -1 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{p} & 0.2 & 0.5 & 0.3 \\
\end{array}$$
and
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{Y} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \text{p} & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Are they independent? What should there be instead of the question marks?

Comment: Please check my edited question!

Comment: But what is the total probability of $X$ having any value? And what can you conclude from it?

Comment: That would be 1. Well I guess I should replace them with calculated probabilities. Anyways, that is not the point of my question. The point is how can I then add those distributions.

Comment: My point was to make you do some work, because it seems you didn't put much effort into the question. Usually, that would get your question closed or put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you develop the product $(0.2+0.5+0.3)\times(0.3+0.4+0.3)$, you will get nine terms corresponding to the probabilities of occurrence of all pairs of values from $X$ and $Y$, each pair giving a certain sum. Grouping the terms with equal sums and adding their probabilities, you will get the requested distribution.

Hint: there are $7$ distinct sums.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint I:** $\quad\mathsf P(X\!=\!-1)+\mathsf P(X\!=\!1)+\mathsf P(X\!=\!3) = 1$

**Hint II:** $\quad\mathsf P(X+Y\!=\!2) = \mathsf P(X\!=\!1, Y\!=\!1) +\mathsf P (X\!=\!-1, Y\!=\!3)$

**Hint III:** Independence means *what*?

$$\;\\[2ex]
\begin{bmatrix} ~ & -1 & 1 & 3 
\\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 4
\\ 2 & 1 & 3 & 5
\\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 6
\end{bmatrix}$$